# Sel_CallFuncN cannot cast void to Sel_CallFuncN

Tags: cocos2d-x, splash-screen

I'm trying to get an intro screen in my game. After a few seconds it should change to the game itself.

In the Init of my introscreen class, I try to make a sequence, but I'm getting the following error:

> cannot cast from type void to member pointer type
>   'cocos2d::SEL_CallFuncN' (aka
>   'void(cocos2d::CCObject::*)(cocos2d::CCNode *)'

here's my code:

```
 bool IntroScreen::init() {
    if (!CCLayer::init()) {
        return false;
    }

    cocos2d::CCSize screenSize = cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

    cocos2d::CCSprite* logomarca = cocos2d::CCSprite::create("rayman_intro.png");
    logomarca->setPosition(ccp(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2));
    this->addChild(logomarca, 1);

    cocos2d::CCFiniteTimeAction *seq1 = cocos2d::CCSequence::create(cocos2d::CCDelayTime::create(3.0),
                                                  cocos2d::CCCallFuncN::create(this,
                                                                               cocos2d::SEL_CallFuncN(cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(Controller::scene())), NULL);

    this->runAction(seq1);

    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scheduler` here instead of `CCFiniteTimeAction` like this..

```
    this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(IntroScreen::replace), 3);


void IntroScreen::replace(CCObject* sender){
    cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(Controller::scene();
}
```

Also insert a statement "`using namespace cocos2d;`" at the top to avoid writing `cocos2d::` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

in SEL_CallFuncN you should put pointer to function not the function

For example

```
 cocos2d::SEL_CallFuncN(IntroScreen::replace)
```

In replace put the code you want to invoke, if you use CallFuncN your method should have in first parametr place for object, which run the function

```
void IntroScreen::replace(CCObject* sender){
    cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(Controller::scene();
}
```